# finding all the polynomials of degree 4 under conditions

Tags: polynomials, roots

i am trying to find all the polynomials $p(x)$ of degree 4 that meets the following requirements:

1. for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ $p(x)\ge0$
2. $p(1)=0$
3. $p(2+i)=0$

so far i know that $(x-1)$ , $(x-(2+i))$ and $(x-(2-i))$ are roots of that polynomial and i am trying to find another

Comment: could just have a double root at $1$...

Comment: @thesmallprint Indeed you need a double root so that the polynomial stays positive - otherwise there would be a non-zero derivative.

Answer (score 2):

What about $p(x)=(x-1)^2\bigl(x-(2+i)\bigr)\bigl(x-(2-i)\bigr)=x^4-6x^3+14x^2-14x+5$?

Comment: i changed the question i am trying to find all the polynomials that meet the requirements are there any others?

Comment: @Lendion Sure. Take my $p(x)$ and multiply it by a real number greater than $0$.

Comment: but why doesn't it change the polynomial

Comment: @Lendion It *does* change the polynomial, unless the number that you chose is $1$.

Comment: sorry i meant roots

Comment: Because if $ a\neq0$, then $ a.p(x)=0\iff p (x)=0$.